# How to put whitespace into Yasnippet Templates?

Tags: yasnippet

When I create a new yasnippet template using the 'yas-new-snippet' command, I'm unable to get the leading whitespace to show when the template is expanded in a new document or even tested using 'yas-tryout-snippet'.

For example:

```
interface t1 
    description 
    no shutdown
```

Becomes:

```
interface t1 
description 
no shutdown
```

How can I get the leading whitespace to show when I expand?

The snippet is saved as text-mode.

I'm using GNU Emacs24 with a new installation of Yasnippet from MELPA.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `expand-env` directive, as described in the [manual](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-2-5).

E.g.

```
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed) (yas-wrap-around-region 'nil))
```